# Can we do Mantra japa while consuming non vegetarian on a daily basis?

Tags: mantras, food, non-vegetarian, gayatri-mantra, sandhyavandanam

I have a particular condition which makes me unable to consume more carbohydrate food. I usually stay active and consume a balanced diet with meat included. Lately I wanted to start sandhyavandan and japa of gayatri mantra and kaal bhairav mantra daily. Can I do that while following my current food habits? I know that meat is a rajasic food. Please Someone elaborate.

Comment: Namaste, Welcome to HSE! If you could edit the question and restrict it to something like elaborate on dos and Donts of meat consumption and the Kshatriya Sandhyavandanam part it would be nice. Reason: there is a slight personal element involved and as per site policy, personal advice questions are liable to be closed. So of you could edit it, the question will not be closed. :)

Comment: IMO I dont think there is anything against meat eating in the Vedas. Happy to stand corrected if this not the case

Comment: you don't need to to eat meat to get protein. you definitely must not eat meat to get spiritual advancement.

Answer (score 9):

Since you're a dvija, it should be known that eating the meat of un-sacrificed animals is highly sinful:

> [Manu 5.33](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200410.html) - In normal times the twice-born man conversant with the law shall not eat meat unlawfully; having eaten it unlawfully, he shall, after death, be devoured by them helplessly.

What is lawful meat?

> [Manu 5.36](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200413.html) - The Brāhmaṇa shall never eat animals that have not been consecrated with sacred texts; but those that have been consecrated with sacred texts, he shall eat, taking, his stand upon the eternal law.

So as a dvija, if you eat meat, you have committed a sin and are liable for prayaschitta.

> Can we do Mantra japa while consuming non vegetarian on a daily basis?

There is a verse from the Upanishads:

> The Vedas do not purify one of bad conduct.

So if one willingly and continually commits heinous sins, the Vedic rites like gayatri japa, sandhyavandana, etc. may not purify him.

Comment: Which Upanishad is that verse from?

Comment: Devibhagavatam:11:19 states that japa of the Gayatri 10,000 times is effective in cleansing heinous sins like brahmahatyā, then what to speak of the sin of eating unconsecrated meat.

Answer (score 5):

**Japa Yoga**, a famous treatise by *Swami Sivananda Saraswati* speaks about the code of conduct of a person practicing *Japa*:

On **Page 114** of the [text](http://japa-yoga.org/japa.pdf) under the title **Rules to be observed During Japa**, *Sivananda* writes:

> [image]

- **Japa** is done to elevate the *sattva guna* of a person , which ultimately helps them in *spiritual progress*. Any activity that inhibits the same, therefore, should be strictly avoided.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. The idea that fish and meat are bad is a post-Buddhistic idea. A spiritual aspirant has the option of eating fish and meat if he wants after not eating it for a year.

> He who thus knows this Yajnayajniya Saman, woven in the limbs of the
> body, is endowed with all the limbs, and is not crippled in any limb;
> he reaches the full length of life, lives gloriously, becomes great
> with offspring and cattle and great also with fame. His holy vow is
> that he should not eat fish and meat for a year, or rather, he should
> not eat fish and meat at all.

**Chandogya Upanishad 2.19.2**

> Are there no asses and the like to whom home and forest are the same
> and who wander about naked without shame? Do they become yogins
> thereby? If men could get liberated by coating themselves with mud and
> ashes, are all the country-folk who live in mud and ash, freed?
> **Denizens of the forest like deer and other animals live only on grass,
> leaves and water; do they become yogins thereby?** Frogs and fish live
> all their lives in rivers like the Ganges; do they acquire special
> merit thereby? Pigeons eat nothing but stone; the chataka bird does
> not partake of the water on earth; are they too yogins thereby? Truly,
> such privations and the self-denials are only for deceiving the world.
> The only means for liberation is the knowledge of the Truth, the
> Divine.

**Kularnava Tantra, Human Birth and Life, Readings by M.P. Pandit**

What is the Kularnava Tantra passage saying? It is saying that mechanically following vegetarianism won't lead to release. I am posting some Garuda purana verses that say the same thing.

> Some fools infatuated by my illusion wish for moksha by torturing
> their bodies by fasts, taking cores but once in a day.
>
> Can the ignorant fools get release by torturing their body? Can a
> serpent die simply by beating the hole wherein it dwells?
>
> The imposters who guise themselves with matted hair and deer-skins and
> pretend to be pious move about deceiving people.
>
> For him who takes delight in the pleasures of the world and pretends
> that he knows Brahman, both karman and Brahman are far distant.
>
> Alike at home and in forest, naked and shameless, the donkeys move
> here and there. Do they become unattached?
>
> If men achieve release by anointing mud and ash will they be released?
>
> Jackal, mouse and **dear live in the forest and consume grass, leaves
> and water. Are they also ascetics?**
>
> From their birth to death, frogs and fish stay in the river such as
> Ganga. Do they become Yogins?
>
> Doves, Silaharas and Catakas do not drink water from earth. Are they
> Vratins?
>
> People are content with their routine work. But that does not help
> them to reach their goal. It is the knowledge of truth or reality that
> effects release.

**Garuda Purana, Dharma Khanda, Chapter XLIX**

All spiritual practices are about cleansing the mind.

Comment: The verse you cited says not to eat meat: "he should not eat fish and meat for a year, or rather, he should not eat fish and meat at all."

Comment: and, what is that Truth ? :-)

Comment: You are misleading users again by selectively quoting those Kularnava Tantram verses. Those verses are saying that a Yogi can't be recognised by his habbits. Or that Moksha can never be achieved by following particular lifestyle or diets. The first few chapters of the same text condemn meat eating outside of rituals in the same way other scriptures do like Manu Smriti etc.